# Can Lion detect 1920x1200 screen resolution?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, video, resolution

I own a MacBook Pro, 17", MA897D/A, A1229, Mid 2007, with a display resolution of 1920x1200 which worked seamlessly under 10.4.

As I upgraded to Lion I sadly noticed that the maximum resolution now is 1680x1050.

Did anybody experience similar behaviour?
Is Lion unable to detect the native resolution?
Are there any 'power settings' I could use?

Comment: I am assuming you have the optional 17" Wide SCreen TFT. The standard spec for the 2007 17" only supports 1680x1050, however, the optional TFT does support 1920x1200. Specs [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP17) and [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP13)

Comment: Have you booted in safe mode and gone to the System Information app - chosen Window - About this Mac and made sure the OS itself is reading the Display correctly. You do get 90 days of phone/online service support and you might get the fastest answer by calling on Apple to get to the bottom of this if the drivers didn't install / operate correctly.

Comment: That is correct. Your monitor's native resolution is 1680x1050 (as Diago has pointed out). Lion is operating normally.

Comment: No, Diago and cksum. As I pointed out the native resolution of 1900x1200 works on Mac OS X 10.4 Tiger.

Answer (score 1):

The current 17" MacBook Pro which ships with Lion also has a native resolution of 1920 x 1200:

http://www.apple.com/macbookpro/specs-17inch.html

My guess is Making a new user or booting into safe mode will help you sort out whether something got munged in your user account in the Lion install.

Comment: His MBP is not the current model, it is one from 2007 which did offer a high-res screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would try:

Open /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist with a PLIST editor. Look under DisplaySets > Item 1 > Item 1 for the "Width" and "Height" values. Change them to 1920 and 1200 respectively. Save, restart, see if it fixes it.